CS50 Tideman: lock_pairs not correctly locking all non-cyclical pairs despite appearing correct
I am working on the Tideman problem from the CS50 course (see Problem Set 3 - Tideman), and I am having an issue with my lock_pairs function. The function is intended to lock pairs of candidates without creating cycles, but I am encountering unexpected behavior.
I have implemented the function to iterate over pairs and attempt to lock them in a way that prevents cycles. While my implementation passes certain test cases, I am not confident that it is robust enough to handle all scenarios. I suspect I might be missing something related to cycles.
I have tried to check for cycles manually in my code without recursion (I only realized recursion might be needed after Googling post-implementation), and I was working under the assumption that I could not modify the code outside the provided function definitions (i.e., no additional helper functions).
The course specification allows modifying the lock_pairs function as long as no cycles are introduced. However, I am unsure if my approach is correct or if I am just getting lucky with my test cases and the candidate orders I've tried. I would greatly appreciate feedback on whether this implementation is correct or if there's a flaw in the logic.
Background:

Problem set: CS50 Tideman
The function must lock pairs of candidates into a graph without creating cycles.
I initially forgot about recursion for cycle detection.

Here's my current implementation of lock_pairs:
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    int lastloser;
    int winnerloser = MAX + 1;

    for (int r = 0; r < pair_count; r++)
    {
        int losercheck[MAX] = {0};

        // Check each locked pair if false (empty), store only the loser index
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                if (locked[i][j] == false)
                {
                    losercheck[j]++;
                }
            }
        }

        lastloser = 0;

        // Check how many currently are all empty by comparing to candidate count
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (losercheck[j] == candidate_count)
            {
                // Store quantity of empty loser columns in lastloser
                lastloser++;
            }
        }

        // If last loser == 1, leave it blank to declare a winner
        if (lastloser == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
            {
                if (losercheck[j] == candidate_count)
                {
                    winnerloser = j;
                }
            }
        }

        if (pairs[r].loser != winnerloser)
        {
            locked[pairs[r].winner][pairs[r].loser] = true;
        }
    }

    return;
}

My Question:

Is this implementation correct for ensuring no cycles are created while locking pairs?
Is the manual checking method I've employed effective, or is recursion necessary for checking cycles, as suggested in the problem hints?
Are there any edge cases where this implementation might fail that I might not have tested?

I am happy to provide additional context if necessary. Thanks in advance for your help!

I would look at the "Related questions" links on this page. I would also encourage you to read carefully the CS50 walk-through of the Tideman program paying particular attention to "which set of pairs can a cycle occur on". This opens up two approaches. Also note the sort-order the pairs must be in before the cycle check. The search-box at the top of the page will provide many, many more examples if you simply search "tideman lock pairs".  (I know there are at least a half-dozen solutions on this site -- probably more) Drop a comment if still stuck.

Please post a minimal reproducible example.

@DavidC.Rankin Iv seen the solutions and i am going to try reclusion anyway because i want to learn how to do it, but my question was to know if my code how it is now is correct and if i found away around reclusion that still works. I did impliment sort pairs before this function and it does all work fine so i just wanted an experienced coder to cast an eye over it and see if there is any obvious errors in my coding because it would be good for my own self confidence as a new coder to know that i can code complicated problems correctly with my own solutions and not needing to google.

That is the way to do it. However, you may simply want to write a procedural function to check for cycles first rather than trying to write a recursive solution. Recursion brings with it many subtle complexities regarding the placement of the exit-test and recursive call. Remember CS50 isn't a "Teach you to code" course, it is simply a set of problems that exercises what you have "already learned". To that end, visit The Definitive C Book Guide and List Coding is a wonderful game of chess -- that takes practice.

Last note, CS50 isn't without its faults. Every time you see string, you should think char *. string is just an unfortunate choice of a typedef to hide the use of a character pointer from the user - but instead confuses many new C programmers into thinking there is a string type in C. I presume you caught that. Which is why you generally want learn a language from a peer-reviewed book. Online tutorials can wander from the standard. Never use competitive coding sites as a "learning" tool. They demonstrate some of the worst coding practices in their intro code. They are exercise sites.

Hint, I'll assume you have Tally. The critical part of the logic is Sort: Sort the pairs of candidates in decreasing order of strength of victory, ... and Lock: Starting with the strongest pair, go through the pairs of candidates in order and “lock in” each pair... Now since you sorted in decreasing order of strength of victory and are going through the pairs in order locking in each pair -- which pair is the ONLY pair where a cycle can occur? (which explains why you sort in decreasing order and then go through in order...)

This may help. This implementation allows you to see the intermediate steps for the voting, sorting and locking when you define DEBUG (see top of file for instructions). Tideman w/Debug Output. It also provides an example input file (the 9 votes with cycle where Charlie wins) so you don't have to type the candidates each time (just redirect the file to the program). Add the REDIR define for this to show the input. This is just one example following the instructions in the prior comment.

@DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the advice, i will definitly check out the book! i think my uncle might actually already own it so i can borrow off him :). i was able to work out my lock_pairs function with recursion. turns out i was just implimenting the wrong algorithm, my way of doing it was just to figure out which pair would have all losers as false, meaning it is the last loser to become a loser, implying it is the winner. However, i now see that i was suppose to check for CYCLES, which is now so obvious im disapointed i didnt think of it sooner.

Don't feel bad. The purpose of the CS50 problems are to expose you to just this type of thinking. We have all experienced sore-foreheads from proverbially beating our heads against the wall on similar problems. Tideman not only introduces the graph concept, but is a great indexing exercise. If it were easy -- it wouldn't provide much of a challenge. That is one area where the CS50 exercises are quite good -- they make you apply a good range of basic programming skill to arrive at a correct solution. Good luck with your coding.
